# Backing up Gmail using IMAPSize

Tags: gmail, contacts, backup

I am trying to backup all my contacts who sent me mails in Gmail. One way of doing is by using IMAPSize to back my account.

But while configuring my account, I get the following error:

> Can’t connect to server imap.gmail.com. Host is not valid or port is incorrect

Any idea?

Comment: Have you enabled IMAP in your Gmail settings? Are you using port 993?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems IMAPSize is not able to establish an encrypted connection through port 993. My email provider allows connection through un-encrypted connection and port 143 and this works.

Answer (score 1):

As John said, make sure you have IMAP enabled in Gmail's settings. If you're connecting to port 993, make sure IMAPSize knows this port expects SSL connections.

When you say you want to "backup all my contacts", do you mean you want to backup emails exchanged with them or just their name and addresses? If its the latter, have a look at context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/contacts

(disclaimer: I'm the founder of Context.IO)